# How to get wms layer's extent OpenLayers3?

Tags: geoserver, wms, layers, openlayers, extents

Here is a part of my code:

```
var wms = new ol.layer.Tile({
            source: new ol.source.TileWMS({
                url: 'localhost:8080/geoserver/BEIS_WS/wms',
                params: {
                    'LAYERS':'BEIS_WS:mahalle_alan', 'cql_filter':'tmno=1453'
                },
                serverType: 'geoserver',
            }),
            opacity: 0.4
        });
        wms.setProperties({ attributes: {}, type: "exampleLayer" });
        map.addLayer(wms);
```

I googled but I did not find the answer, is there any way to get wms layer's extent in OpenLayers3? After I added layer, result on console is here:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you mean minimum bounding box of your data that the WMS is rendering you need to make a separate call to geoserver ([WPS](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/extensions/wps/index.html)) to get that given that your datasource is in a vector format. Or you could call the REST-API to get the configured bounding box of the layer.

Comment: Thank you for your response @koordo , I will try your suggestion.