# how to get Extent or BoundingBox from geoserver in openlayers3

Tags: openlayers-2, geoserver, openlayers

I use wms layer from geoserver on my map and i use openlayers3 api.
I want to zoom to my selected layer but for this i have too use extent of my selected layer.

```
mySelectedLayer=map.getLayers().getArray()[map.getLayers().getLength()-1];
mySelectedLayer.getExtent()// result is undefined
```

why?

Answer (score 1):

It seems you didn't search before asking or I misunderstand. You can already have the answer [at this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/119480/how-to-get-wms-layers-extent-openlayers3).

**Edit due to comment**

Ok, WPS can be a bit annoying. So, another way is to call GetCapabilities if you use a WMS. You can convert the XML result to JSON and extract layer extent. See [this official example](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.0.0/examples/wms-capabilities.html) illustrating the concept.

Comment: I saw that answer but i dont know how to use or control wps services in openlayers3